# How can I expose more than 1 port with Dockerfile/Nginx/Heroku

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, flask, heroku

I'm able to expose 2 services **locally, on my computer** with the following command `docker run -d --name @containerName -e "PORT=8080" -p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000 @imageName`.

On port 5000, I expose my backend using a flask-restful api and on port 8080, I expose my frontend using nginx to serve my react.js application.

When **I deploy that on Heroku platform** I have 2 problems :

1. It seems Heroku try to bind Nginx on port 80 but the `PORT` env var is different, log's output :

- Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:5000\ app:app\ --daemon\ \&\&\ sed\ -i\ -e\ \'s/\34352/\'\"\34352\"\'/g\'\ /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\ \&\&\ nginx\ -g\ \'daemon\ off\;\'`
- nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
- [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)

2. How can I write the `-p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000` part inside the Dockerfile or hack around it since I can't specify the `docker run [...]` command on Heroku ?

I'm new to Docker and Nginx, so I would be very grateful if you know a better way to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Temporary image for react.js app using a multi-stage build
# ref : https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM node:latest as build-react

# create a shared folder and define it as current dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# copy the files required for node packages installation
COPY ./react-client/package.json ./
COPY ./react-client/yarn.lock ./

# install dependencies, copy code and build bundles
RUN yarn install
COPY ./react-client .
RUN yarn build

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Production image based on ubuntu:latest with nginx & python3
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM ubuntu:latest as prod-react

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# update, upgrade and install packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y nginx curl python3 python3-distutils python3-apt

# install pip
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py

# copy flask-api requirements file and install modules
COPY ./flask-api/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

# copy flask code
COPY ./flask-api/app.py .

# copy built image and config onto nginx directory
COPY --from=build-react /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./conf.nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Serve flask-api with gunicorn and react-client with nginx
# Ports :
#   - 5000 is used for flask-api
#   - 8080 is used by nginx to serve react-client
# You can change them but you'll have to change :
#   - for flask-api    : conf.nginx, axios calls (5000 -> @newApiPort)
#   - for react-client : CORS origins (8080 -> @newClientPort)
#
# To build and run this :
#   docker build -t @imageName .
#   docker run -d --name @containerName -e "PORT=8080" -p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000 @imageName
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --daemon && \
sed -i -e 's/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: You only get a single Internet-routable port on Heroku, no matter how you use it. Either use two apps (one for each service) or, depending on your use case, reconfigure your application to run on a single port. One example might be to route all requests to `/api/...` to one service and anything else to the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already get your solution working, serving the frontend by Flask using Catch-all-URLS routing. I rode it was a bad security and a low-traffic solution only : do you know a well-known website using that kind of solution ? Can you link a reference for your point of a single internet-routable port on Heroku ? And can't I only publish the frontend on internet-routable port and passing all requests on /api/... to the gunicorn server running on another port (not internet-routed) ?

Comment: Hosting your front-end and back-end separately is definitely more flexible as it lets you scale them independently. Maybe that's what was meant by "low-traffic solution only" wherever you read that? I'm not sure what you mean by "bad security". Heroku's port model is well-documented [in the official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos) and [in questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+port). Requests from your front-end _come from_ the internet (from your users' browsers), so no, you can't respond to them on a non-routable port.

Comment: I probably explained it wrong, I'm trying to setup Nginx as a [reversed proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). So I want to expose React.js app with Nginx on an internet port and access to my api only thought the Nginx setup as a reverse proxy.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Your React app will be running in a browser. When your app makes an HTTP request it comes _from that browser_, over the Internet. You need to listen for requests from the Internet, reverse proxy or not.

Comment: @Chris, yes it makes a big difference. You can actually achieve that using all the machine's ports instead of only the one exposed to http, usually 80, that is published under any ip address. This is exactly what a reversed proxy does.

Comment: Again, _you only get **one port on Heroku**_. Anything you want to do that requires multiple ports on a single app _**will not work**_.

Comment: On that specific part and after some further research, yes, agreed. Is there any similar cloud host that allow using multiple ports ?

Comment: "On that specific part"—that's what your question is _about_. If you aren't asking about opening multiple ports anymore you should't be commenting on this question. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. If you have a new question, please ask it in a separate question. But asking us to find or recommend off-site resources, like a hosting provider, are explicitly off-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic].